# I have a String List with 10 elements inside. I need to randomly add 3 elements from the 10 into a WPF listbox (one element on each line) in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, list, random, listbox

```
    List<string> topLevel = new List<string>();
            

            topLevel.Add("000");
            topLevel.Add("100");
            topLevel.Add("200");
            topLevel.Add("300");
            topLevel.Add("400");
            topLevel.Add("500");
            topLevel.Add("600");
            topLevel.Add("700");
            topLevel.Add("800");
            topLevel.Add("900");
```

I tried

```
  var random=  topLevel.Distinct().OrderBy(x => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(3);
            lst2.Items.AddRange(random.ToArray());
```

But I get an 'AddRange' as underlined error and I do not know how to fix it

Comment: `Take()` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`. Why are you calling `ToArray()` ???

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Idk some other guy on stack overflow said I must do this but it wasn't working, can you please show me exactly what to do please?

Comment: If it is red-underlined then you could see the error message if you hover the mouse on the underlined text. What is the error message?

Comment: Just stop calling `ToArray()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```cs
    // Initial list source of values
    // This MUST be an observable collection
    private readonly ObservableCollection<string> lst2Source
        = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "1", "2" };

    // Immutable list of adding values
    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> topLevel
        = Array.AsReadOnly("000 100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900".Split());

    public SomeWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Source is assigned once after XAML initialization
        lst2.ItemsSource = lst2Source;
    }

    private readonly Random random = new Random();
    private void AddRandom(int count)
    {
        topLevel
            .OrderBy(_ => random.Next())
            .Take(count)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(level => lst2Source.Add(level)); // Elements are added not to the UI element, but to the value source
    }
```

> it just prints 1 and 2 into my listbox

> that i cannot lst2.items.clear();

"1" and "2" are the initial list values for the example. If they are not needed then remove them.
To add random elements, call the AddRandom(...) method.
To clear the collection, call lst2Source.Clear().

Comment: Perhaps you should explain to the OP why this will work.

Comment: @Steve , I have added comments to the code.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield the error was 'ItemCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no accessible extension method

Comment: @EldHasp what does new ObservableCollection<string>() { "1", "2" }; do and when I copy your code into mine it just prints 1 and 2 into my listbox

Comment: @donaldD There is no AddRange method for the Items collection in WPF. You should use the code presented here. My suggestion to look at the error message was all about this.

Comment: @Steve ohh ok, but the code above only prints out 1 and 2 in my listbox instead of 3 random elements in the array

Comment: No idea what you have tried. But, just to be sure, do you call the AddRandom(3) somewhere in your code?

Comment: @Steve so it works now, but ive got another issue, so it shows the 3 random elements but when i try to reset the listbox to show different elements i get an error saying that i cannot lst2.items.clear(); this is the error: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.'

Comment: @Steve I just realized that this code will not work for me, is there a simpler way to do it in a normal method?

Comment: @donaldD , Read the addition to my answer.